# How to load the generaled html from a php file? loadHTMLFile not working

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to get the generated HTML from my index.php page. I need to create a CSV file from an HTML table that I generated with PHP.

My problem is I can't manage to get my HTML table in a PHP variable.

I have tried using `loadHTMLFile` but it doesn't seem work with php files.

I also tried using `file_get_contents` but it gets the content before PHP is executed so there is PHP in the middle of the table.

Anyone knows how I can manage to do that?

Comment: Use Ajax to load it or simply include the file

Comment: Why not just create the CSV data the same time you create the HTML data?

Comment: Make sure you load the HTML file, and not the PHP file. That means using the http:// protocol when you retrieve the file.

Comment: @CD001 The script I'm working on will be ran by a cronjob to do daily savings of that HTML table.

Comment: You'll need to open the file over HTTP since you're going to want to see the HTML output of the file rather than the *actual* (PHP) contents of the file - you could use cURL for this or possibly `file_get_contents` with the `allow_url_fopen` option enabled, e.g. `file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/path')` ... that should work with `DomDocument::loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/path')` as well but you **have** to use the full URL.

Comment: Thank you @CD001. `file_get_contents` does work with the full URL but I will use cURL because I also need to login to the website to access the data I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @CD001 for the answer. There are 2 solutions : `file_get_contents` or using cURL.

`file_get_contents` with the full HTTP URL works well. I will use cURL because I also need to login to the page

Thank you guys.

Comment: Yeah cURL would be my preferred solution - I'm not keen on enabling things like `allow_url_fopen` without good reason :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ob_start();
include 'http://domain/file.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

Thanks

Comment: AIUI it's a PHP file which echoes out HTML and it's that HTML output that's desired - so, this won't work.

Comment: @CD001: Actually, it might work. You buffer the HTML output, and store it in a variable. You can use that to save the HTML to a file.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware In this instance though there is no `.html` file; what this would do is buffer the PHP code to the `$html` variable not the HTML output from that PHP code.

Comment: Now it *should* work if you've got `allow_url_fopen` enabled as you're including the file over http.

Comment: @CD001: Yes, of course. I said it might work. You have to use the http:// protocol. As you saw I changed sunil's example. Yes, `allow_url_fopen` is also needed, but then it really might work. ;-)

Comment: @sunil it wasn't the file extension that was the issue but the fact that originally your code was accessing the file over the filesystem **not** over http - so it would read in the source code rather than the output - and in this instance the source was PHP that generates HTML on the fly. KIKO's edits are actually what would make it work.